# Write empty RDD with Headers to output file Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have condition where I need to generate output file with only headers. I have used below dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Spark Java Code

```
 JavaSparkContext context = SparkBean.getInstance().getJavaSparkContext();
 JavaRDD<Row> emptyRdd = context.emptyRDD();                                
 SQLContext sqlContext = SparkBean.getInstance().getSparkSQLContext();  
 DataFrame tpDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(emptyRdd,Common.createSchema(ConfigItems.getCitywiseSchema()));
 tpDf.coalesce(1).toJavaRDD().saveAsTextFile("citywise.csv");
```

Output generated with citywise.csv folder, inside I can see only success file no part file.

**Expected Output**

> citywise.csv/part-00000

```
cat citywise.csv/part-00000 
header1,header2,header3
```

**Update**

I have used below code also

```
tpDf.coalesce(1).write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save(FileName);
```

No output part file

Does anybody know how I can implement this?

Comment: `sc.makeRDD(tpDf.columns).saveAsTextFile(..)`

Answer (score 1):

Before answering question I should mention that you've to avoid using the `RDD` (legacy API), you should instead use the `DataSet/DataFrame` (Structred API). for more information about the diffrence between the three api and why the structed api is much better the the RDD one please refre to [this databricks article](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html%22this%20databricks%20article%22).

Now answering your question :

I'm coming from scala but I do believe that there's a very similar way to do that in java and python since you're using the structured API :

```
tpDF.write.option("header", true).save("test")
```

Hope this helps you. Best Regards

Comment: For those who are wondering, this is the [actual article URL](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html)